# MAKE: automatic variables to reference path segments

Tags: windows-7, makefile

In any Windows-compatible MAKE-style tool, what automatic variables let a recipe reference individual segments of a multi-directory target pathname? E.g. at ?1? and ?2? in:

```
all: target\loud\short\bing.wav target\quiet\long\bong.wav 

target\%.wav: source\%.wav
 convert -infile=%< =outfile=$@ -volume=$?1? -duration=$?2?
```

where when % in target\%.wav matches loud\short\bing , ?1? returns loud and $?2? returns short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU make there aren't any automatic variables for path components like that (nor can there really be since the path could be arbitrarily deep) but you can get those components easily enough.

`$(word 1,$(subst \, ,$*))` should get you `loud`.

`$(word 2,$(subst \, ,$*))` should get you `short`.

Escaping on that `\` might need tweaking on Windows. I don't have make on Windows handy but that code above works fine on linux with `/` in paths (and `\` too for that matter in a quick test).

Comment: "With GNU make there aren't any automatic variables for path components like that (nor can there really be since the path could be arbitrarily deep)" I use other tools that reference the components of an arbitrary-depth path but counting from right to left, so I should have put my ?1? and ?2? in reverse order. Thanks for the word function solution. I'll take that no directory name contains a space :) .... until GNU adds $(word n,text,sep).

Comment: Indeed, spaces will be a problem for this but they are a problem for make in a handful of other ways already without this. What other tools? And how high does their numbering go?

Comment: "What other tools?" Audio tools inc. MediaMonkey and dBpoweramp. "And how high does their numbering go?" MM uses numbering up to 9 at least. dBpa uses one construct per level skipped and has no limit IIRC.